# Let $n$ be an odd positive integer. Show that $24 \vert(n^3-n).$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Let $n$ be an odd positive integer. Show that $24 \vert(n^3-n).$

So since $n^3-n=(n-1)n(n+1)$, we have that $3\vert(n^3-n).$

Also since we have that $n$ is odd we can say that $n=2k+1$, for some $k \in \mathbb{Z^+}.$

This implies that $(n+1) = 2k +2 = 2(k+1)$, hence $2\vert(n+1).$ Similar argument can be made for $(n-1)$.

Now $24 = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4$ so essentially I'm only missing the part where I would have to show that $4$ divides some of the terms. How can I find that?

Comment: $3\vert(n^3-n).$ so it suffice to prove $8\vert(n^3-n).$

Comment: Could also approach this by induction.

Comment: If two even numbers have a difference of 2, is it possible that neither is divisible by 4?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that $n(n^2-1)$ is divisible by 24, if $n$ is an odd integer greater than $2$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2508927/show-that-nn2-1-is-divisible-by-24-if-n-is-an-odd-integer-greater-than)

Comment: Duplicate of, for example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2508927/show-that-nn2-1-is-divisible-by-24-if-n-is-an-odd-integer-greater-than   or  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2508927/show-that-nn2-1-is-divisible-by-24-if-n-is-an-odd-integer-greater-than or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233094/prove-24-divides-u3-u-for-all-odd-natural-numbers-u/2222405#2222405

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is odd, then both $n-1$ and $n+1$ are even.

Either $n-1$ or $n+1$ must be a multiple of $4$ since for every pair of  consecutive even numbers, one of them is a multiple of $4$.

Hence $8$ divides $n^3-n$.

Answer (score 0):

Only remaining to show $8\mid (n-1)n(n+1)$.

Observe, for an odd $n$, one of $n-1$ and $n+1$ is divisible by $2$ and another one is divisible by $4$.

So $(n-1)(n+1)$ is divisible by $8$, if $n$ is odd.

Answer (score 0):

Let n be an odd positive integer, so $n=2k+1$ so $$n^3-n=(n-1)n(n+1)\\
=(2k+1-1)(2k+1)(2k+2)\\=2k(2k+1)(2k+2)\\=4k(k+1)(2k+1)\\=4\underbrace{k(k+1)}_{even=2q}(2k+1)\\=4(2q)(2k+1)$$